# How can I better dynamically generate radio buttons and text labels into a span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can I get this function to write dynamically generated radio buttons

A) more elegantly...like in jQuery...

B) or at least how to automatically generate radio buttons with text labels of Something and SomethingElse (equal to the quantity entered into a text field that fires the function call) into a span called areas3.  Thanks!

```
function tshirtForm(form)

{

textAreas3 = document.forms['frmCreateCheckboxRange'].qty_item_3.value;
var container3 = document.getElementById("areas3");
document.getElementById("areas3").className = "textboxwide";
var shirtText = "<b>Please select a size and a color:</b><br />";
var newtext1 = document.createTextNode(" Red ");
var para1 = document.getElementById("areas3");
var newtext2 = document.createTextNode(" White ");

    for(i=0; i<form; i++)
    {

        alert(form);
        field1 = document.createElement("input");
        field1.type = "radio";
        field1.name = "color";
        field1.id = "red";
        field1.value = "Red";

        field2 = document.createElement("input");
        field2.type = "radio";
        field2.name = "color";
        field2.id = "white";
        field2.value = "White";

        para1.appendChild(newtext1);
        document.getElementById("areas3").appendChild(field1);
        para2.appendChild(newtext2);
        document.getElementById("areas3").appendChild(field2);



    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

That code looks a bit messy, you repeat `document.getElementById("areas3")` a lot of times, you only need to fetch an element once.

I find that it is typically a lot simpler to use the innerHTML feature to alter a website.

```
document.getElementById("areas3").innerHTML=
"<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Stack Overflow<\/a>"
```

Basically just generate a string of the HTML you need and set the innerHTML feature of an element to that string, anything the element already contain will be overwritten.

Comment: Yeah, tried that first off, but it was not giving me the HTML elements like the radio buttons that I wanted.  Just the text.  So I decided to get very granular and print out everything I'm doing with the DOM so I could just SEE what was happening.

Comment: Now I have this to print the labels next to the radio buttons (this happens in the loop that counts how many rows of buttons we need):  
  label1 = document.createElement("label");
  color1 = document.createTextNode("Red");
  firstLabel = label1.appendChild(color1);
  label2 = document.createElement("label");
  color2 = document.createTextNode("White");
  secondLabel = label2.appendChild(color2);
                document.getElementById("areas3").appendChild(firstLabel);
  document.getElementById("areas3").appendChild(field1);...and so forth...

Comment: It seems that innerHTML won't work inside my counter loop for some reason.  It just writes out one line of radio buttons and then stops when I need like 3 lines of radio buttons.

Comment: You should only set innerHTML once, use the loop to generate the string, and after the loop, set innerHTML to that string. It works, and it works in all browsers, at least all the way back to IE6, if only you use it right.